# PHP scripts missing <?php won't run

Tags: php, apache

I've downloaded a module library for Yii in which every PHP file starts with this:

```
<?
```

...rather than:

```
<?php
```

On my local Apache server, these files get loaded as flat files, rather than as executable scripts, though the files are all modded as writable and executable. Is there a way to force these files to be run as PHP, or do I have to modify all the files (and there are probably a hundred of them).

Comment: If you can’t modify your server configuration, search and replace is your friend :)

Comment: I think I can, but what an annoying way to write a module. Blech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to enable [`short_php_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) from php.ini Or better change `<?` to `<?php` in your file.

> Tells PHP whether the short form () of PHP's open tag should be
>   allowed. If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can
>   disable this option in order to use  inline. Otherwise, you
>   can print it with PHP, for example: '; ?>'. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of
>   the PHP open tag ().

Comment: +1 for the advice to use `<?php` as using short tags are considered [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) due to reduced portability of the code. (Of which this is a clear cut example). *Beware though*: Coders that use short tags usually also make heavy use of the [echo shortcut syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), making your code harder to convert to regular tags!

Comment: @RemcoOverdijk: Thanks and yup I didn't want to go in details of why short tags should be avoided, just given a simple advice :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to activate the

```
short_open_tag
```

in the php.ini from "Off" to "On".
Dont forget to reload/restart the apache

Answer (score 2):

you can add a .htaccess file with the following line to make it work:
php_value short_tags on